# asp.net wiki software which forces users to enter certain information?

Tags: asp.net, wiki, wiki-engine

I would like to use an asp.net based wiki. However it needs to have the capability where when a user creates or edits a page, certain information needs to be in the page and be in the same section (fixed) of the page.

For example if I want to use a wiki to create a restaurants review site, I want the name of the restaurant, address, hours of operations be entered and they always show up in the same place in the page so all the pages have a standard look.

Is there such a wiki software that can handle this? The wiki needs to be open source so I can make modifications (hopefully not much)

I know ScrewTurn is popular. Can it handle my needs?
(don't just list a few asp.net wiki's without picking one which accomplishes what I want)

Comment: Yes, ScrewTurn would work. It gives you several different ways of customizing each page: customizable headers, footers, sidebars, etc. or full "themes" where you have control over the CSS and images. And of course, you can just modify the code to spit out different HTML...

Comment: Looks like asp.net doesn't have many wiki's. I used Wikimatrix.org and it up with 3 candidates and ScrewTurn seems to the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Screwturn, I think that you could use [Phlanger](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=F8079) to run Mediawiki under ASP.net. It is open source, and it is easy to customize the pages to have a standard look.